# How do I convert quarterly time series to a table format without year and quarterly labels?

Tags: r, dataframe

My aim is to transform my quarterly time series data to a table format without having labels to the years and quarters on the columns. I also don't want serial numbers.

I have the **dput** of the data here:

```
dput(rainfall)
structure(c(26.3333333333333, 129.5, 250.8, 59.5666666666667, 
29.0333333333333, 157.8, 138.1, 68.6, 55.3, 196.2, 118.033333333333, 
120.733333333333, 31.0333333333333, 166.5, 48.2666666666667, 
91.4333333333333, 24.3333333333333, 113.933333333333, 98.3666666666667, 
69, 50.2, 171.2, 142.7, 88.4, 26.7, 172.433333333333, 251.733333333333, 
58.1666666666667, 26.1, 125.433333333333, 273.5, 91.7, 22.5666666666667, 
158, 156.466666666667, 48.5333333333333, 46.3333333333333, 126.4, 
92.9, 37.1333333333333, 2.36666666666667, 184.233333333333, 94.6666666666667, 
50.9333333333333, 30.9333333333333, 177.566666666667, 184.266666666667, 
60.7333333333333, 39.3333333333333, 150.566666666667, 299.7, 
68.0666666666667, 49.0666666666667, 168.533333333333, 133.5, 
59.9, 53.4666666666667, 141.6, 281.4, 75.3333333333333, 41.9666666666667, 
200.8, 176.233333333333, 94.5666666666667, 30.2333333333333, 
139.333333333333, 207.4, 45.8, 6.93333333333333, 146, 163.166666666667, 
67.2, 20.0333333333333, 201.133333333333, 201.8, 48.1666666666667, 
18.9666666666667, 138.6, 169.733333333333, 64.1666666666667, 
79.5, 131.866666666667, 159.6, 70.4, 21.2, 78.4333333333333, 
163.833333333333, 96, 48.5, 177, 196.333333333333, 62.1333333333333, 
37.6333333333333, 119.366666666667, 243.666666666667, 49.4333333333333, 
35.3666666666667, 161.1, 121.166666666667, 111, 3.6, 98.3333333333333, 
88.7333333333333, 74.1, 63.8666666666667, 187.7, 183.566666666667, 
115.866666666667, 36.2333333333333, 126.066666666667, 240.833333333333, 
35.4333333333333, 27.0666666666667, 192.2, 186.366666666667, 
17.4833333333333, 15.5166666666667, 166.633333333333, 238.65, 
77.6833333333333, 38.2833333333333, 125.983333333333, 188.916666666667, 
94.1666666666667, 20.8666666666667, 174.916666666667, 110.8, 
66.6, 42.6333333333333, 206.25, 161.5, 56.5333333333333, 22.6666666666667, 
106.116666666667, 173.166666666667, 44.3666666666667, 5.31666666666667, 
193.406666666667, 177.266666666667, 71.2833333333333, 33.2833333333333, 
168.6, 221.366666666667, 41.2666666666667, 22.8, 180.866666666667, 
118.7, 49.4833333333333, 39.95, 170.533333333333, 260.783333333333, 
170.833333333333, 68.9666666666667, 157.833333333333, 250.733333333333, 
90.1166666666667, 46.6833333333333, 149.356666666667, 175.65, 
68.3, 54.6833333333333, 166.65, 131.183333333333, 80.6833333333333
), .Dim = c(164L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "rainfall"), .Tsp = c(1973, 
2013.75, 4), class = "ts")
```

This is the code I used:

```
library(zoo)

new_data <- data.frame(yq = yearqtr(index(rainfall)), val = rainfall)
```

Here is the output:

```
         yq   rainfall

1   1973 Q1  26.333333

2   1973 Q2 129.500000

3   1973 Q3 250.800000

4   1973 Q4  59.566667

5   1974 Q1  29.033333

6   1974 Q2 157.800000

7   1974 Q3 138.100000

8   1974 Q4  68.600000

9   1975 Q1  55.300000

10  1975 Q2 196.200000
```

I don't want the serial numbers and label on the quarter column.

Looking forward to hearing from anyone who may assist.

Comment: what do you want on the `yq` column? also what do you mean by *serial numbers*?

Comment: I don't want any label on ```yq``` column. I want it blank, by **serial number**  I mean the first column which has the row numbers

Comment: First the row numbers MUST BE THERE is a dataframe unless you are writing it to a file. Also your `yq` column. what label do you mean? I do not see any label

Comment: This what I want
         
                 rainfall

1973 Q1  26.333333

1973 Q2 129.500000

1973 Q3 250.800000

1973 Q4  59.566667

1974 Q1  29.033333

1974 Q2 157.800000

1974 Q3 138.100000

1974 Q4  68.600000

1975 Q1  55.300000

1975 Q2 196.200000

Comment: That is exactly what you have. Check the output

Comment: It's not giving the desired result

Comment: Can you include the desired results in your question. Also REMEMBER that ALL dataframes have a rownames. So the sequence 1,2,...10 IS NOT part of the output

Comment: I want my table to look like the ```Canada``` data:
       
library("vars")

Canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what you want without the question showing what it is but maybe you want this which gives a zoo object which displays as shown:

```
as.zoo(rainfall)
##           rainfall
## 1973 Q1  26.333333
## 1973 Q2 129.500000
## 1973 Q3 250.800000
## 1973 Q4  59.566667
...snip...
```

or in terms of new_data this gives the same output.

```
read.zoo(new_data, drop = FALSE)
```

or maybe you want one of these which give data frames with the year/quarter as row names.

```
as.data.frame(as.zoo(rainfall))
##           rainfall
## 1973 Q1  26.333333
## 1973 Q2 129.500000
## 1973 Q3 250.800000
## 1973 Q4  59.566667
...snip...
```

or this gives the same output but is in terms of new_data:

```
as.data.frame(read.zoo(new_data, drop = FALSE))
```

---

The description of "serial number" is unclear and the output shows what you don't want rather than what you do want so we really don't know what it is but maybe these will help:

```
c(cycle(rainfall))  # 1, 2, 3, etc. (the quarter number)

paste0("Q", cycle(rainfall))  # Q1, Q2, etc.

quarters(time(as.zoo(rainfall)))  # same

format(time(as.zoo(rainfall)), "Q%q")  # same
```

If what you meant is how to display new_data without the row names:

```
write.table(new_data, row.names = FALSE)
```

or without row names and without the year/quarter column:

```
write.table(new_data[, 2, drop = FALSE], row.names = FALSE)
```

or in terms of rainfall

```
write.table(rainfall, row.names = FALSE)
```

Note that these give a one column data frame and matrix in terms of new_data

```
 new_data[, 2, drop = FALSE] # data frame
 cbind(rainfall = new_data[[2]]) # 1 column matrix
```

or in terms of rainfall:

```
 as.data.frame(rainfall) # data frame
 rbind(rainfall) # 1 column matrix
```

Comment: Have made another guess as to what it is that the question is asking for. See top of answer.